# Testing on a 720 4.3" Windows Phone emulator

Tags: testing, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

A beta tester of mine has reported a layout issue where my LayoutRoot container has unnecessary left and right margins. He is having this problem on his HTC 8X. This is a 4.3" 720p device.

I've tested the app on all Windows Phone emulators available, and have not seen this problem. But there doesn't appear to be a 720p 4.3" emulator available for me to test against.  Is there any way I can test it using these device properties (screen resolution = 720p, and screen size = 4.3") without actually owning the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), on Windows Phone 8.0, the 720p **scaled** resolution is the same that the 1080p, which is 480 x 853.

That means that layout of the app should be identical between both resolutions, and that what you see on the 1080p emulator will be the same that on a 720p device (unless you have different image assets for each resolution).

The physical screen size doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks as always Olivier for the knowledge. I'm not using any image assets though, and this is not a problem on any 1080p emulator or actual device even. I know it's difficult to diagnose without seeing the code, but any rough idea what might be the issue here?

Comment: I may think it has to do with hard coded values I use in places. But the problem is I can't really test the fix without a 4.3" 720p emulator or device

Comment: As I said, the layout should be exactly identical between the 720p device and the 1080p emulator. Maybe you should ask for a screenshot from the beta tester, to be convinced.

Comment: Hah, I actually did. Unfortunately it's true.

Comment: There is a difference between the 720p layout and the 1080p one? That's weird. Can you show a screenshot of both?

Comment: Okay I'm on my PC now and looked at the screenshot that was sent to me - the problem I thought there was actually isn't. Basically I misunderstood the problem because 1) he didn't explain it clearly and 2) when opening the screenshot on my phone, there were black left and right margins and so I thought that's what he meant to be the issue. I'm assuming 2) is happening on the phone because of the dimensions of the screenshot possibly (720 * 1280) causing it to be letterboxed. Anyway, looks like it was a false alarm basically. So sorry for wasting your time! But thanks for giving it :)

Answer (score 0):

As Olivier Payen says, The physical screen size doesn't matter.

So, you're asking to test your application on the device which you've not owned. In that case, you can use [Remote Device Access](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/remote-device-access)

Remote Device Access (RDA) is a service that allows developers to test their mobile applications and services remotely on various Nokia devices based on Windows Phone, Nokia X, Asha, Series 40, and more.

So, try installing your app on the remote device and see your app's resolution and scaling are.!

Comment: Potentially invaluable resource, no idea it existed. But don't think there are any 720p 4.3" Lumia devices to help me do a like for like test.

Comment: yep. i am just telling the way to test your applications on the device which you've not owned.