# Layout is different in Windows Phone 4.3" WVGA

Tags: layout, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I have developed an app for Windows Phone 8.1 and everything was fine, till I got a report about layout problems in Lumia 720. It has a 4.3" 480x800 screen. Now, my layout is fine on 4.0" and on 4.5", but on 4.3" objects overlay, or text is truncated . The only article I found similiar to this topic is this

[Testing on a 720 4.3" Windows Phone emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054776/testing-on-a-720-4-3-windows-phone-emulator) .

Unfortunately it does not give a solution for my problem, because both 4.0" and 4.3" have a resolution 480x800.

Is there a way to get the physical screen size of the device, so at least I can arrange the layout for 4.3" separately.

Also, there is no emulator for 4.3" in Visual Studio. Is there a way to test the app without a physical device?

Edit:
Screenshot on 4"

[image]

Screenshot on 4.3"

[image]
.

Don't mind the blurred text.

Comment: Have you screenshots, and XAML to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I edited the question. Both have 480x800 resolution.

Comment: Are you usign somethign to scale based on DPI?

Comment: Not really. Grids for example have auto height and width. The problem is I can't even debug my app. I don't have a 4.3" device, nor there is a 4.3" emulator.

Comment: *Something* is making the  device use a different font size, which is odd, as these are normally defined in the XAML.

Comment: I guess its due to ppi .. having same resolution on a larger screen must cause text to enlarge.

Comment: you can query the actual screen size per [Taking Advantage of Large-Screen Windows Phones](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/22/taking-advantage-of-large-screen-windows-phones/)